# Inserting JSON into HTML

Tags: html, json

Let's say I have a JSON file like the below. How can I insert a specific value (e.g. 0.69) into a HTML page?

```
{
    "species":1,

    "animal":[
        {"day": 1,"weight": [0.69,1,2,3],"amounteaten": [22,16,15,14],"emergencies": [0,0,0,0]},
        {"day": 2,"weight": [0.5,1,3,4],"amounteaten": [22,17,15,14],"emergencies": [0,0,1,0]}

    ]
}
```

Comment: Whence is this JSON?  Are you getting it from JavaScript?

Comment: I made the JSON up, it's a standalone file. Let's call it intro.json. From what I know, I seem to need to create a Javascript file and then insert the Javascript file into the HTML. Is that correct? (Or can I insert it into a HTML file directly?) @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp) which explains how you can use the `JSON.parse()` function to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

```js
$.getJSON('intro.json', function(obj) {
    document.getElementById("foo").textContent = obj.animal[0].weight[0];
});
```